# Django - Change the max_length error message on a CharField TextInput

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to customize the error message displayed when a user inputs text longer than the max length for a CharField in my model. The model defines the field as follows:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I have a ModelForm for this model that defines the form field as follows:

```
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"span8", 'placeholder':'e.g. How do I setup a wi-fi network? How to sync my iPhone with iCloud?'}),
                            error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a question.', 'max_length': 'Your question is too long.'})
```

This works fine for the 'required' error message, but the 'max_length' error message still uses Django's default message here. Am I doing something wrong or should this text be customized in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'max_length'` is checked by `'django.core.validators.MaxLengthValidator'`, which has hard-coded error message. You could replace it w/ your own version by:

```
# after the name or ModelForm definition
name.validators[-1].message = 'Your question is too long.'
```

Comment: That worked, but after the name definition in the Model. I tried putting it after the name definition in the ModelForm but at that point name.validators is an empty list.

Comment: @JamieForrest The validator only applied for `form.CharField` having not `None` `max_length`. You could check `isinstance(validator, MaxLengthValidator)` for validator inside validators instead of hard-coded `[-1]` also

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure from which version it is working, but now you can do this:

```
class YouForm(forms.ModelForm):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.fields['you_field'].error_messages = {'max_length': 'Ensure this value has at most %(limit_value)d character (it has %(show_value)d).'}
```

Comment: what if we want to ignore this validation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create subclass of `'django.core.validators.MaxLengthValidator'`

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class MyValidator(MaxValueValidator):
    message = 'Your question is too long.'
```